# Use function in expression in attribute

Tags: angular, function, expression

I have an Angular 4 component and I want to use the return value of a function as the quoted string in a selector attribute; for example:

```
<img class="" src="{{ myfunction(1) }}" style="width: 50px;">
```

It generates a 404 error in the browser with this invalid link:
http://localhost:4200/assets/images/configuration/interfaces/icon-function%20toLowerCase()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D.png

The first part looks right, but the last doesn't make sense.  Here's the code:

```
   public static myfunction(itype: EInterfaceTypes) {
        let retval: string = "";
        retval = "/assets/images/configuration/interfaces/icon-" +
            myService.e2string(itype, true).toLowerCase + ".png";
        return retval;
    }
```

I can't seem to find a syntax that works properly.  Can someone explain what's wrong?

As a related issue, should myfunction encompass the returned string in double quotes - or just return the string (in this case a file path).

Comment: It should work, any error ?

Comment: Could you post the result of your myfunction(1) or its code ? Is there an error in the console ?

Comment: I added the code and error message above

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a function, you need to add `()` to the end of it.

Comment: That worked - that seems like the simplest solution (vs Robert solution below) in case you want to post as answer

Answer (score 0):

HI can you do like this

**template**

```
 <img class="" [src]="myfunction(1)">
```

in your **componet**

```
private userImage:string="" //default image path

myfunction(input){
    return this.userImage ? this.userImage : "app/portal/market-place/marketplace-banner.jpg"
}
```

This is working for me can you use that